# How to use JavaScript to call a data file then display in a table form

Tags: javascript, html

myObject.js

```
var myObject= {"customers":[
{"CustomerName" : "Alfreds Futterkiste","Country" : "Germany"},
{"CustomerName" : "Berglunds snabbköp","Country" : "Sweden"},
{"CustomerName" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma","Country" : "Mexico"}
]};
```

Display.html

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>CustomerName:</th>
      <th>Country:</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I import the **myObject.js** into the **Display.html** and then display into this kind of format without using any library

```
---------------------------------
|customer name    | country     |
----------------------------------
| Alfreds ....    | Germany     |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: iterate through `myObject.customers` creating appropriate elements and adding them to the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would inmport the js like any other external js file

```
<script src="js/myObject.js"></script>
```

This will then give you access to the data via `myObject.customers`.

Iterate through the customers array, build a string of each row and then insert that string as the html of the table body.

Note the object destriucturing on each iteration - allows for a simpler structure to the code and aliasing of long names of the obect properties.

```js
var myObject= {"customers":[
{"CustomerName" : "Alfreds Futterkiste","Country" : "Germany"},
{"CustomerName" : "Berglunds snabbköp","Country" : "Sweden"},
{"CustomerName" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma","Country" : "Mexico"}
]};


const customers = myObject.customers;
let tableStr = '';

// iterate over he array and create strings of the td's
customers.forEach(function(customer, index){

  //destructure the object to give nicer aliases for the iterations.
  const {CustomerName: name, Country: country} = customer;
  
  // build the string with the contents of the iterated row data
  tableStr +='<tr>';
   tableStr +='<td>' + (index + 1) + '</td>';
   tableStr +='<td>' + name + '</td>';
   tableStr +='<td>' + country + '</td>';
  tableStr +='</tr>';
 })
 
 // insert the string as the html of the tbody
 document.querySelector('#customers-table tbody').innerHTML = tableStr;
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

table, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 10px
}
```

```html
<table id="customers-table" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>CustomerName:</th>
      <th>Country:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```